# .net regular expression integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

[image]I am trying to create a regular expression in C# that allows only alphabet characters and spaces.
i just tried this.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Name")]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
[RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z])",
ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Correct Name")]
```

Comment: Do you have any queries related to my answer. I saw that you unaccepted and again accepted my answer. If you have any doubts please let me know

Comment: i have a little issue when I'm inserting a data its giving me a error  The model backing the 'newvalidContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Comment: Issue which you mentioned in comment is not related to what you asked earlier. I would suggest, instead of editing your previous question, Post one more question with error which you metioned in comment. Last edit will will mislead other SO users

Comment: ok thank u I'm posting a new question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
[RegularExpression("^([A-Za-z ]+$)",
ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Correct Name")]
```

---

**Description**

`^` - Beginning of string

`[ ]` - Brackets specifies set of characters

`A-za-z` - All capital/small letters

- Consider a space

`+` - one or more letters

`$` - Indicates end of string

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[A-Za-z\s]+` it will matches alphabet characters and spaces

```
[RegularExpression("[A-Za-z\s]+", ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Correct Name")]
```

`\s` matches any whitespace character